# Add onfocus listener instead of onload

Tags: javascript

I have such script in js file wich I'm calling from jsp, and I need to add listener instead of "onload".
What important for me:
1) It must be pure js without jQuery or anything
2) Input tags would be created dynamically(Maybe this is important)
3) It must be external js file(`<script src="<c:url value="/js/focus.js" />"></script>`), but not the tag `<script>function.....</script>` inside jsp page

```
    onload = function () {
        var allInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i = 0; i < allInput.length; i++) {
        allInput[i].onfocus = showHint
    }
};

function showHint() {
    var hint = document.getElementById("hint");
    hint.innerHTML = this.name + " " + this.value;
    hint.style.display = "block";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works for me

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var allInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < allInput.length; i++) {
        allInput[i].onfocus = showHint
    }
});

function showHint() {
    var hint = document.getElementById("hint");
    hint.innerHTML = this.name + " " + this.value;
    hint.style.display = "block";
};
```

Comment: That will do if it works for you. Turn's out you just wanted to replace `onload` with `addEventListener`. Your title misleaded me.

Comment: @grabantot Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

The page can get focus before is't loaded. And if the page is not loaded your inputs don't exist so `window.onfocus` can't set `allInput[i].onfocus`. When the page is refreshed with the focus on the devtools the page gets a chance to create inputs before `window.onfocus` call.

Put your `window.onfocus` inside `window.onload` so that it is always called after the page is loaded. If you don't want to override `window.onload` use `addEventListener` instead:

```
addEventListener('load', function () {
  addEventListener('focus', function() {
    var allInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for (i = 0; i < allInput.length; i++) {
      allInput[i].addEventListener('focus', showHint)
    }
  }
})

function showHint() {
  var hint = document.getElementById("hint")
  hint.innerHTML = this.name + " " + this.value
  hint.style.display = "block"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Please take a look on my answer that works for me. Maybe you'll give some cons and pros.

Answer (score 0):

replace `onload` with `onfocus`

```
onfocus = function () {
        var allInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i = 0; i < allInput.length; i++) {
        allInput[i].onfocus = showHint
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but it works only when the Chrome devtool is open

Comment: @Vitaliy Rybkin see my answer to find out.